# subprocess call, returns 127 with full path supplied

Tags: android, python, shell, subprocess, kivy

I am trying to run a test script via python, here is the line of code:

```
subprocess.call('mocha /Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/tests/testLoginPage.js --platform android',shell=True)
```

It returns 127 'directory not found', however if I copy and paste the exact string in the call argument, into shell it works fine.

Please help

Comment: So you are doing this on your Android devive?

Comment: yes, I have an emulator running already

Comment: And why not use a real device? And which shell are you referring to?

Comment: I could use a real device, it makes no difference. and unix shell....

Comment: And this unix shell is running where?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything like `mocha` available on any Android device by default and this command runs the ***Android*** shell. Also, I don't think there's basically **any** `/Users` directory available on your phone, therefore a path such as `/Users/User/Documents/...` definitely doesn't exist.

Use [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree) or any other explorer that lets you browse the whole storage and see for yourself. If you don't want to download the application, just use ADB. Also a useful thing for you might be a [reference](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference) to the Android console.